# How do I create a single global hotkey in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, hotkeys

How would I create a global hotkey in C++ such that I can press only 1 key to trigger it?

For example, what would I do if I want to press "P" globally to trigger a pause event in my application?

*Note: the RegisterHotKey function needs a modifier (Ctrl, Shift, Alt, or Win key)*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: raw input registered using the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag

Comment: When you say "globally" you mean while your application window is not focused?

Comment: @MatG Yes, that is what I mean

Comment: `RegisterHotKey` does not need a modifier, this works: `::RegisterHotKey( /* HWND */ Handle, 0, MOD_NOREPEAT, 'P' );` however I would register a function key